# Sitemap in XML format or XHTML format?

Tags: format, sitemap

Hello
What would be the most suitable format for sitemap files?
XML or XHTML?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present the sitemap as a document for human consumption than HTML (or XHTML (which is XML FWIW)) makes sense.

If you want to present it for machine consumption, then some other data format, such as Google's [Sitemap](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) (which is also XML) would make sense.